# ps -aefyl is not showing full command

Tags: unix, solaris

I am trying to see full CMD value for command `ps -aefyl` but it is showing by truncating.

I am using SunOS Solaris 5.1.

Any clue?

Comment: There is no Solaris 5.1. I also strongly doubt you are running SunOS 5.1 which is 18 years old. You are more likely running Solaris 10 (SunOs 5.10).

Answer (score 3):

Also note, that `/usr/ucb/ps` with `-ww` will show you full cmd of commands of which you are owner only.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used:

```
/usr/ucb/ps -auxwww
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the -w option, which means 'wide' (132 columns, to be specific).

For even more fun, try -ww (its meaning left as an exercise for the reader). :)

Comment: No -w is not working, it says not a valid option. It works on IBM AIX but not on Sun Solaris

Comment: @goutham: `/usr/ucb/ps` contains the "other" version, which supports the -w option.

Answer (score 1):

try using the pargs command, check the man page
"man pargs"